# Retrieving Data from an URL JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve data from an external JSON file. The website has an api which allows public access. My problem is that I can not access the data. Now I display undefined. Well to be honest I think this is impossible to do with some access from te sever side. Now is there a way with php and the curl function?

```
var dataFromServer;
function getPrice() {
  $.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/api/flax",
  success: handleData(dataFromServer)
});
}

function handleData(data) {
document.write(data);
//do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages (e.g. in the console?)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, could you please read through [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide all relevant information for the case? Such as maybe the error message? :)

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is come from "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

for more info of it you can check this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

you can use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/api/flax",
  success: function(e){console.log(e);}
});
```

Comment: Maybe the data is not publicly accessible? It should be, their site is here. http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/api/?info

Comment: I believe need to have a header that allows the data to be taken, which is server side. Now can I retrieve the data using php?

Comment: For such problem we have two method 1)set header parameter on the server side. 2) using jsonp

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail Omidam81? Please.

Comment: How can I use jsonp if there is no callback within the url?

Comment: I thought data.id, data.average, data. etc would get me some information, but I can not retrieve anything. Updated my code.

Comment: I can get the data file now, but i still get this error Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html. My data is undefined, but i know the callback worked

Comment: I am working with php, i have the data i want from the site. I can not believe i could not get the jsonp to work.

Answer (score 0):

Include that in the HTML header :

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>
```

and then use this code (JS) :

```
$.getJSON(
     'REPLACE_THAT_WITH_THE_JSON_URL',
     function(data){
         var tr;
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append('<td>' + val.jsonfield + '</td>');
            $('table').append(tr);
         });
       });
```

Just replace the URL and the jsonfield. An example is shown here : 
[LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/NOT.html)